# Where store or implement global variables ($) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use/implement global variables in Rails. I tried the following:

In **config/environments/production.rb**:

```rb
$n_exams_question = 20
```

In **config/environments/development.rb**:

```rb
$n_exams_question = 3
```

I want to use different values in production and development. My localserver is not detecting the global variables. Where is the best place to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails does it that way:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration

In `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.myGlobalVariable = 'blabla1'
```

In `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.myGlobalVariable = 'blabla2'
```

then use this Anywhere:

```
Rails.configuration.myGlobalVariable
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that answers your question or if it's a good practice, but I would have used the environment variables.

To do this, I use the gem [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)

Example :

In your **application.yml** file

```
development:
  N_EXAMS_QUESTION: "15" # ENV['N_EXAMS_QUESTION']
production:
  N_EXAMS_QUESTION: "20" # ENV['N_EXAMS_QUESTION']
```

You can call this value with ENV['N_EXAMS_QUESTION']